# How to get submitted data to controllers action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im new to rails , i coudnt able to understand that , how could i get data from submitted form.

As this is my  form registerduser.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag("/submitform", :method => "get") do %>
<%= label_tag(:q1, "id:") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:q1) %>
<%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

How do I get submitted values in this action

```
def submitform
  @customers_values = params[:q1]
end
```

routes.rb

```
get "customers/submitform"
```

error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/submitform"
```

Comment: It's not so hard. Just read documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters

Comment: Whatever fields the form has, they get converted into a Ruby Hash and can be accessed via `params`.

Comment: i have gone through document but will  be helpful  if any  one makes it clear with small  sample(to get id from form )

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameters hash accessible from controller (as well as view) with `params` method. For example, you can have value of your text field with:

```
params[:q1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `form_tag` does not include the full path.  From your route (curious syntax, btw), I can see that you want it to be `customers/submitform`.  Look at your error message.  It's looking for a route that does not have customers in the path.  Change your `form_tag` to `customers/submit_form`.